# Adding taxonomy filter at the top of image gallery

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've spent some time trying to discover how can i add taxonomy filter at the top of the gallery view in Drupal 7. I've created View called Gallery which contains of images,title and author. In content type I've declared that it is a term reference to Gallery type taxonomy. My purpose is to allow user to sort the image gallery by tag, simple example would be animal gallery, for example:

> 'all' 'pigs' 'dogs' 'cats'
>
> 'image' 'image' 'image'
>
> 'title' 'title' 'title'
>
> 'user'  'user'  'user'

So far I've created this View of images,title and author, I've no idea how to include taxonomy tags. I hope this explanation is understandable. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your taxonomy field in the "Filters" section of the view. In the filter settings, select the option "expose filter to users".

It will add a taxonomy filter in your view, based on the terms from the vocabulary selected in your field.

It will allow users to filter the view by taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

You can create menu block with items/links which you need and then add this block into views header via [Views block area module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area)

Comment: I'm checking up with exposed filters now. I'll try what you offer, if this fails. Thanks.

Comment: check this article http://wearepropeople.com/blog/views-taxonomy-links-as-exposed-filter-with-ajax-enabled-for-drupal-7